# How to access variable from different class scope

Tags: java, ros

I'm trying to create  that uses the java_rosbridge library, but I am having issues with accessing and updating the variable `status` between class scopes.

```
    Boolean isDoorbellRinging() {
        Boolean status = false;
        bridge.subscribe(SubscriptionRequestMsg.generate("/doorbell").setType("std_msgs/Bool").setThrottleRate(1)
                .setQueueLength(1), new RosListenDelegate() {

                    public void receive(JsonNode data, String stringRep) {
                        MessageUnpacker<PrimitiveMsg<String>> unpacker = new MessageUnpacker<PrimitiveMsg<String>>(
                                PrimitiveMsg.class);
                        PrimitiveMsg<String> msg = unpacker.unpackRosMessage(data);
                        
                        logger.info(data.get("msg").get("data").asText());
                        status = ((data.get("msg").get("data").asInt() > 0) ? true : false);
                    }
                });

        return status;
    }
```

It's receiving the data correctly as I get the correct output with logger.info(..) when not trying to access `status`. However, when including `status = ((data.get("msg")...`
I'm currently receiving this error:

```
Local variables referenced from an inner class must be final or effectively final
```

Comment: It is not allowed to reassign any variable from inner class (in your case you are trying reassign variable status defined in outer class in MessengerUnpacker). Therefore you are receiving this error

Answer (score 0):

What that message means, is that in closures (lambdas and methods in anonymous classes), after their definition, variables from outer scope must not be reassigned. You can circumvent this using containers (collections, arrays, atomics, and so on). In this case, `AtomicBoolean` may come in handy: define your variable as `AtomicBoolean` and use `set` instead of assignment. If you have to distinguish between `null` and `false`, use `AtomicReference<Boolean>`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it was able to compile, however `status` is still false from the function scope :(

Comment: @chris it seems like your function is a callback, which means the value will be assigned *after* the function returns. Are you sure it's being called?

Answer (score 0):

'status' is on a stack frame corresponding to the execution of isDoorbellRinging().

The 'receive' call presumably will execute at some future time. At that point, isDoorbellRinging() will have returned. There will be no 'status' to modify. It will have ceased to be.

By the same point, isDoorbellRinging() cannot 'now' return a value that will be determined at some point in the future.

You need some way to handle the asynchronous nature of this.